# Is is possible to have the grid row number be changed through orientation state triggers?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

So first off I have a TableView that contains a TableRoot and TableSection, the TableSection is populated through TextCells being added in C# from data being grabbed. I would like to have it so that when you change the Orientation (portrait or landscape) I want the number of rows to increase or decrease. I know there are some properties to can apply to the Grid, but so far none seem to be something like `MaxGridSize`. For example with portraits max size being 1 and landscapes being 3.

Heres some code that I already have written

C#

```cs
foreach (var reply in grpcReply.grpcResult)
{
    QuerySection.Add(new TextCell
    {
        Text = $"{reply.FieldOne} {reply.FieldTwo}",
        Detail = $"{reply.FieldThree} {reply.FieldFour}"
    });
}
```

XAML

```xml
<TableView Intent="Menu"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    x:Name="QueryView">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Results" x:Name="QuerySection">
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

I want it to look this:

Orientation Landscape:

TC TC TC TC TC

TC TC TC TC TC

Orientation Portrait:

TC

TC

TC

TC

TC

This is what I have tried

```cs
int rowCounter = 0;
int columnCounter = 0;

foreach (var reply in grpcReply.grpcResult)
{
    if (rowCounter == 3)
    {
        rowCounter = 0;
        columnCounter++;
    }
    Label label = new Label
    {
        Text = $"{reply.fieldOne} {reply.fieldTwo}"
    };
    QueryGrid.SetColumn(label, columnCounter);
    QueryGrid.SetRow(label, rowCounter);
    QueryGrid.Children.Add(label);
    rowCounter++;
}
```

This is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5gye.jpg)

Comment: Please share some code along with your explanation. What exactly do you want to achieve? It's totally possible to change the number of rows and columns using `OrientationStateTrigger` (like I describe in my [blog](https://ewerspej.hashnode.dev/add-responsive-layouts-to-your-maui-app)), but there is no `MaxGridSize` property or similar. You can only specify the exact amount of rows when using XAML. You can change the row count dynamically in the code-behind, though. However, you'll need to provide more information to actually be able to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: I added some code, but I don't think it's very helpful with this. Okay so I want to achieve when you flip the orientation of the phone the grid that I have in my app has 3 rows, when you flip it back it then has only 1 row.

Comment: I'm reading your blogpost right now (thank you), so does "RowDefinitions" say how many rows you'll have in each column? And if so in my C# code while I add the text elements to my grid I wont need to specify what row it goes into?

Comment: Well, that actually applies to a [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid), not a TableView, but the idea would be the same. Yes, the `RowDefinitions` define the amount of rows and their individual heights, where `RowDefinitions="50, auto, *"` would mean three rows, one of height 50 (device independent units), one that sizes itself based to its content and another one that takes up all the remaining space, if the Grid has a defined total height.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'll be using a Grid inside my TableView (if that works) thank you. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it off as an answer?

Comment: I also would need an infinite amount of columns (technically) if I just leave it blank does that make it infinite? Because now its just listing everything on one line and they're crushed together (unreadable)

Comment: You can leave the `ColumnDefinitions` blank, but you'll need to set a `Grid.Column` value for each item. In code that would be something like `Grid.SetColumn(yourItem, 2)`. AFAIK, this will dynamically add new columns without explicitly specifying them. I won't add this information as an answer just yet, as I'm not sure whether this exactly solves your problem.

Comment: Its not working, originally it was just a black bar now I have this https://imgur.com/a/lav6ElY and heres the code behind it https://pastebin.com/zFpiuihb

Comment: Please update the question with all relevant code and information instead of adding it in comments or using pastebin. A question should describe a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which your question doesn't really do.

Comment: Please help create [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via Github link.

Comment: So I moved this to another thread because I was told to use DevExpress now to show data, but the problem is that it won't even load. If you have experience with DevExpress I have this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75900842/devexpress-maui-will-not-load-into-pre-existing-c-sharp-project-even-though-its