# DevExpress.Maui will not load into pre-existing C# project even though it's already installed on my computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, devexpress, maui

So I created my DevExpress account and I'm trying to incorporate the controls or maui library into my existing Maui project. I added the NuGet package from the [url](https://nuget.devexpress.com/) when you click on the gear icon in the `Add NuGet packages icon` for `Package Sources`. Now I tried forcefully adding the NuGet package into my `csporj` file and while it adds the NuGet package I get this error now

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package DevExpress.Maui.Controls 22.2.4 is not compatible with net7.0-maccatalyst16.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) / android-arm. Package DevExpress.Maui.Controls 22.2.4 supports:
  - net7.0-android31.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)
  - net7.0-ios15.4 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)   BeacongRPC  C:\Users\user\source\repos\proj\proj\proj.csproj    1
```

Before I even typed in the command on my `csproj` file I was able to locate and find the folder in my NuGet folder in programfiles. Now in the `net7.0-windows` folder under dependencies I have an alert Icon next to the NuGet logo and one next to the DevExpress package. The results I've found have not worked as it says to incorporate it into an existing project you must have it show up under the `extensions tab` which it doesn't.

Comment: Well, what is the error message telling you?

Comment: I fixed the issue, my xaml file was targeting all platforms when DevExpress only works for android and iOS.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct fix.

Comment: I don't understand; so how did you handle it in the .csproj to "not use" DevExpress for your maccatalyst or in my case net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0? Thx for a quick help!